# "dead for five minutes" vs "dead five minutes"

Tags: prepositions

I came across this sentence in my dictionary:

> He hadn’t been dead five minutes before those vultures from the media were after his widow.

I am wondering why the prep **for** is not used there.

I also see these sentences:

> Her mother had been dead **for** ten years.
>
> "You're a widow?"—"Yes. My husband's been dead a year now."

It seems to me that **for** is optional. So, are there any differences in those sentences with or without **for**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are circumstances where you can omit **for**, but I don't know of any summary of the situations when it's acceptable. There are few situations where it's not acceptable to use **for**. One example is when you use **be** with the time interval as the object:

> I will be five minutes - *correct*
>   I will be **for** five minutes - *wrong*

One suggestion for when it can be omitted is given in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60566/when-can-i-omit-for-before-a-time-duration), which suggests that it's OK to omit **for** when the time phrase includes **more than**, **less than**, etc.

My impression is that the omission of **for** is a stylistic trick that adds emphasis to what you are saying, for example in this sentence it emphasizes that five minutes is a very short time:

> I was only gone five minutes and they stole my car!

In the same way, emphasis would certainly be relevant to your first example:

> He hadn’t been dead five minutes before those vultures from the media were after his widow.

One could argue that the the widow in the second example wants to emphasize what a long time it seems to her:

> "You're a widow?"—"Yes. My husband's been dead a year now."

Certainly, with **for** included, this would seem a more neutral statement.

Comment: What does *I will be five minutes* mean?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: @dan, It means "I will have finished what I am doing in five minutes".  You could say it in response to the question "How long will you be?" https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/125017/is-how-long-will-you-be-correct

Comment: @dan: I think it's a regional variation. Of course, the idea that's a valid answer to "how long will you be" is begging the question. That's the same construct used as a question. If you google the phrase "will be five minutes", you'll find this question and the phrase "I will be five minutes **late**".

Answer (score 1):

The better option is using "for"

because it is clearer to read, i mean "dead five minutes" can be thought as:
5 minutes being dead, or wasted or something.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the *English Grammar in Use* by *Cambridge University Press*:

> It is possible to leave out **for** (but not usually in negative
>   sentences):
>
> - They've been married (for) **ten years**. (with or without **for**)
> - They **haven't had** a holiday **for** ten years. (you must use for)
>
> We do *not* use **for** + **all** ... (**all day** / **all my life**
>   etc.):
>
> - I've lived here **all my life**. (*not* for all my life)
>
> You can use **in** instead of **for** in negative sentences (**I
>   haven't** ... etc.):
>
> - They **haven't had** a holiday **in ten years**. (= for ten years)

But as you may have noticed the above doesn't apply to your first example. And I guess this is probably because it conveys a bit different meaning:

> He hadn’t been dead [when it was] five minutes before those vultures from the media
>   were after his widow.

If we had 'for' it would mean that he was alive throughout that five-minute period of time but here this is not clear.

Comment: How can you justify inserting "when it was"? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JavaLatte It was my guess which was made regarding the context. Nevertheless, when I hear people saying "the gate had not been closed ten minutes before the flight" I find that they usually mean "...until ten minutes before the flight". Though people surrounding me are not native English speakers.

Comment: The literal meaning may be the same, but there are significant differences in tone between the "until" version and the original. 1)  the original is emphasising the shortness of the interval 2) the original makes the fight the most important event, whereas the **until** version makes the gate closing the most important event.

Comment: @JavaLatte I do believe you are right about the tone, etc. But as you said "the literal meaning may be the same [...] between the 'until' version and the original". However, if we had 'for' in this example it would change the literal meaning. It would mean that the gate was certainly open throughout that ten-minute period. But there is no such implication in the 'until' version and I guess in the original version too. In my view the same applies to the OP's first example, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree that "the door had not been closed for ten minutes" sounds like "the door had been open for ten minutes". That works with closed, because you can open the door again, but it doesn't work with "dead", because you can't un-die. This is all a side-issue anyway. Can you please explain what your "when it was" sentence is supposed to mean? I cannot understand it at all.

Comment: @JavaLatte Sorry for the delay. As for "when it was", I meant that he hadn't been dead at a particular point in time (i.e. 5 minutes before that event). By the way, by saying that "it doesn't work with 'dead'", do you mean that unlike with 'closed', "he had **not** been dead for ten minutes" and "he had been alive for ten minutes" have different meanings?